# To Show That a Certain Module is Not Flat

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products, flatness

> Let $k$ be a field and $R=k[x]$. Let $M=\dfrac{k[x, y]}{(x)\cap(x, y)^2}$.
>   How to show that $M$ is not a flat $R$-module?

I am sorry but I am really blank on this one.

Comment: Your ring only has an $x$, the module has an $x$ and a $y$ and a $t$ in the denominator. Your title had a typo.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Sorry about that. Fixed it.

Comment: Can you give generators for the ideal inthe denominator?

Comment: We have $(x^2, xy)\subseteq (x)\cap (x, y)^2$. I am thinking this must be an equality but am not sure at this point.

Comment: Well, a good start would be to make sure!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez We have $I:=(x)\cap (x, y)^2=(x)\cap ((x^2)+(xy)+(y^2))$, giving $I=(x)\cap (x^2)+(x)\cap (xy)+(x)\cap (y^2)$, and thus  $I= (x^2)+(xy)=(x,^2 xy)$.

Comment: Ok. What criteria do you have to check if a module is flat?

Comment: The definition I know is that $M$ is a flat $R$-module if tensoring with $M$ preserves exactness of short exact sequences.

Comment: Are you sure $R$ is supposed to be $k[x]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $M$ is flat, then it must be torsion-free (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1319101/is-it-true-that-a-flat-module-is-torsion-free-over-an-arbitrary-ring-does-the-r)), but this is not the case: $xy=0$ and $y\ne 0$ in $M$.

Comment: This is nice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let $M=k[x]/(x^2)$, $N=k[x]/(x)$ and $f:M\to N$ the map induced by the identity of $k[x]$. Let $K$ be the kernel of $f$, so that we have an exact sequence $$0\to K\to M\to N\to 0$$ What happens if you tensor this with $k[x,y]/(x^2,xy)$?